# JS: Building an array of repeated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have a bunch of JavaScript objects which are built by iterating two JSON arrays read from a DB, each of the same length. On some occasions one of these arrays needs to consist of the same value, repeated. So, to save space/clutter, instead of storing an array of the same value repeated I'd like to store it with just a *single* value, which is then repeated at 'object construction' time. What is the best (most idiomatic? safest?) way to accomplish this? Currently I'm doing:

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var array2 = [1, 7, 9];

array1.map(function(val, i) {
  var obj = {
    foo: val,
    bar: array2[i] || array2[array2.length-1]
  };
  return obj;
});
```

So if the value of `array2[i]` is undefined then the value at the *last* position in the array is used, so that this gets repeated out to the appropriate length (this also covers the situation where only the last N values in the array need to be repeated, which is also something I need to accommodate).

Are there any problems with this? Is there a better (more elegant, more idiomatic, or whatever) way?

Comment: please add a wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well _simplistically_, the result is just an array of objects as above, for instance, `[{foo: 'a', bar: '1'}, {foo: 'b', bar: '7'}, {foo: 'c', bar: '9'}, {foo: 'd', bar: '9'} ... ]` (the actual objects are substantially more complex, of course, but the principle holds).

Comment: thank you. what you do is ok. you can define a default value for that case.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thank you, that's good to know.